# relative (positioned) div with top-margin inside another relative div

Tags: css

In short, I have a relatively positioned div with the following style:

```
.div1 {
    background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 269px;  
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

and another div in it styled like this:

```
.div2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 815px;
    height: 74px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Interestingly, due to the margin of div2 (child) inside div1 (parent) and the fact that it's positioned relatively, this pushes **div1** (which is the strange thing) down by 100px. Even more interesting, if I either added a border to div1 or wrote something in it, this behavior goes away.

If anyone knows why this is happening and also has a clean solution to this problem, I'd very much like to pick your brain about it.

Comment: div1 is .header and div2 is div.test?

Comment: Yes, @Jawad. Thank you for the question, I did not realize they had different names and I corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of "collapsing margins".

The spec:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

Some easier reads:

- http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing

As already suggested by Aram Mkrtchyan, the easiest fix in this case is probably to add `overflow: hidden` to `.header`. [Here are some more ideas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832218/why-is-padding-to-a-wrapper-div-looks-different-the-margin-to-an-inner-div/8832573#8832573)

Answer (score 3):

there is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/urNRR/

```
.header {
    background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 269px;  
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center top;
    overflow: hidden // add this
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aram, this was indeed an interesting idea