# Why is padding to a wrapper div looks different the margin to an inner div?

Tags: css

I have 2 divs

```
<div id=number1><div id=number2></div></div>
```

Why is

```
#number1 {
    background:red;
}

#number2 {
   background:blue;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

Not the same as

```
#number1 {
    background:red;
    padding:10px;
}

#number2 {
   background:blue;
   height: 200px;
}
```

And in the first case I get white lines at the top & bottom, where it is suppose to be the red color of div 1?
http://jsfiddle.net/ZbCNq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the first case](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EWeDE/), the unexpected behaviour you're experiencing is due to "collapsing margins".

The spec:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins

Some easier reads:

- http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing

You could fix it by:

- Using `padding` on `#number1` instead of `margin` on `#number2`, as you've done in your question.
- Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#number1`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EWeDE/1/
- Adding some padding to `#number1`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EWeDE/2/
- Adding `float: left; width: 100%` to `#number1`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EWeDE/3/
- Adding `display: inline-block; width: 100%;` to `#number1`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EWeDE/4/
- Adding a border to `#number1`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EWeDE/5/
- I'm sure there are more ways.

Answer (score 1):

It because the "Padding" is used for "Block" to "Content" distance.
and "Margin" is Used for "Block" to "Block" distance.

Comment: could you elaborate? I didn't understand

Comment: the content div is should be left floated, it's will works correctly.
 #number1 {
    background:red;
}

#number2 {
   background:blue;
   height: 200px;
    width:200px;
   margin: 10px;
    float:left; //add float here

}