# <body> being pushed down unless I add padding or border to child element

Tags: html, css, margin

I am having an issue where the `<body>` element is being pushed down, creating unnecessary scrollbars equal to the height of the `margin-top` of the `<header>` element unless I apply padding or borders to its child wrapper div.

The code is available at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgdMF/4/).

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: I don't understand what you want it to be..

Comment: Can you reduce the JS Fiddle to only the code that demonstrates the problem? You don't need all the CSS, or all the HTML, just the bits that are problematic?

Comment: I'm not understanding why `<body>` is being pushed down.

Comment: Did you read [the links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832218/why-is-padding-to-a-wrapper-div-looks-different-the-margin-to-an-inner-div/8832573#8832573) about collapsing margins in my answer?

Comment: @thirtydot I did and I read the spec, but I don't understand how it applies to this case. The hierarchy is html>body>div#land-wrapper>header and `<html>`, `<body>`, and the wrapper div all have 0 `top-margin`, so why would having a 150px `top-margin` on the `<header>` element cause a `top-margin` for the `<body>`?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the top margins of `html`/`body`/`#land-wrapper` are all `0`, the same rules still apply. From the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins): "Certain adjoining margins combine to form a single margin. Those margins are said to “collapse.” Margins are adjoining if there are no nonempty content, padding or border areas or clearance to separate them.". The top margins of `html`/`body`/`#land-wrapper`/`header` adjoin because there's nothing to separate them. Here's a more simplified version of the same scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Xnrb8/

Comment: `overflow: hidden` prevents the collapsing because: "Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children."

Comment: @thirtydot Oh, I see now. Thanks for the thorough explanation; it really did help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. It's due to "collapsing margins".

Here's a laundry list of resources to read: [Why is padding to a wrapper div looks different the margin to an inner div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832218/why-is-padding-to-a-wrapper-div-looks-different-the-margin-to-an-inner-div/8832573#8832573)

In your case, the easiest fix is probably to add `overflow: hidden` to your wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wgdMF/5/

```
#land-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```